# How to extract substring between periods in R

Tags: r, regex

I need to create a dataframe from a .csv file containing author references:

```
refs <- data.frame(reference = "Harris P R, Harris D L (1983). Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture. Journal of European Industrial Training, 7(7): 22.")
```

Essentially I want to pull out the coauthors, year of publication, and article title.

```
refs$author[1]

Harris P R, Harris D L

refs$year[1]
1983

refs$title[1]
Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture
```

At this stage, I do not need a publication source as I can get this via `rscopus`.

I can extract authors and years with this code:

```
refs <- refs %>%
mutate(author = sub("\\(.*", "", reference),
       year = str_extract(reference, "\\d{4}")))
```

However, I need help extracting the title (substring between two periods after bracketed date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex works for your minimal example:

```r
refs <- data.frame(reference = "Harris P R, Harris D L (1983). Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture. Journal of European Industrial Training, 7(7): 22.")
sub("[^.]+\\.([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", refs$reference)
#> [1] " Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture"
```

Explanation:

`"[^.]+\\.([^.]+)\\..*"` - whole regex

`[^.]+\\.` - one or more characters that isn't a period, followed by a period (i.e. everything up until the first period)

`([^.]+)\\..*` - start capturing 'group 1' `"("` which contains one or more characters that aren't a period (`[^.]+`) then stop capturing group 1 `")"` at the next period `"\\."` (group 1 now = the title), then match everything else `".*"`

Then, in the sub command, you print group 1 (`"\\1"`).

Unfortunately, you may run into problems with your 'real world' data. Using [rscopus](https://github.com/muschellij2/rscopus) to extract the title might be a better solution to avoid unforeseen errors.

---

Using tidyverse functions:

```r
library(tidyverse)

refs <- data.frame(reference = "Harris P R, Harris D L (1983). Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture. Journal of European Industrial Training, 7(7): 22.")

refs %>%
  mutate(author = sub("\\(.*", "", reference),
         year = str_extract(reference, "\\d{4}"),
         title = sub("[^.]+\\.([^.]+)\\..*", "\\1", reference))
#>                                                                                                                         reference
#> 1 Harris P R, Harris D L (1983). Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture. Journal of European Industrial Training, 7(7): 22.
#>                    author year                                         title
#> 1 Harris P R, Harris D L  1983  Training for the Metaindustrial Work Culture
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>